# Qlikview does not upload what I ask for

Tags: filenames, lines, qlikview

I have this simple script to upload filenames:

```
Files:
LOAD
Distinct
    FileName() as File
FROM [C:\Matias\Capacity Tracker\AllFiles\*];
```

And as a result while running the script, it happens the following:

```
Files << Analyst Time Sheet - Adam W - 0730-0805 0 lines fetched
Files << Analyst Time Sheet - Adam W - 0806-0812 0 lines fetched
Files << Analyst Time Sheet - Agnieszka J - 0702-0708 2 lines fetched
Files << Analyst Time Sheet - Agnieszka J - 0709-0715 3 lines fetched
Files << Analyst Time Sheet - Agnieszka J - 0716-0722 4 lines fetched
```

And so on... 
So, the strange thing is that for the files from "Adam W", doesn't upload anything (no lines fetched). So then, I have the list of files except these ones. I find it very strange, because as I'm just asking for the filename, it can't be a thing of formatting (I think).

Any idea of what can be happening and how could I solve it?

Thank you in advance
Matias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your idea. I tried that and unfortunately I had the same problem. Finally, I solved like this:

```
Files:
LOAD
Distinct
    FileName() as File
FROM [C:\Matias\Capacity Tracker\AllFiles\*];

SET ErrorMode=0;

    Files:
    LOAD
    Distinct
        FileName() as File
    FROM [C:\Matias\Capacity Tracker\AllFiles\*]
    (ooxml, no labels, table is [Task Log])
    Where Not Exists(File,FileName());

IF ScriptError <> 0 THEN

   Files:
   LOAD
     FileName() as File
   FROM [C:\Matias\Capacity Tracker\AllFiles\*]
   (biff, no labels, table is [Task Log$])
   Where Not Exists(File,FileName());

ENDIF
```

Despite they are all .xls files, it seems to be formatting differences between them. So the ones not uploaded at first, they were uploaded by the first statement after (ooxml), or if it failed, by the second one (biff files). Quite strange.
Maybe this is not the best and proper solution, but it was the only one that worked to upload all the filenames from the folder.

Comment: Nothing wrong in [accepting your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), and you should do it indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Although QlikView offers that * option on the filename of the LOAD statment, the results are sometimes a little bit random. I would recomend that you try a different approach and see if it works.

```
For Each FILE in FileList('C:\Matias\Capacity Tracker\AllFiles\*')
  Files:
  LOAD
    Distinct FileName() as File
  FROM [$(FILE)];
 next file
```

Hope this helps.